# Only have one collapsable block open at one time

Tags: jquery-mobile-collapsible

I have a jquery exapandable list, currently when i click a link it opens IN ADDITION to any open previously. How can I change this so if I had mobile open then i click Landline, it opens landline but also closes mobile? I only want one item to be open at any one time.

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        setTimeout(function() {
            // Slide
            $('#menu1 > li > a.collapsed + ul').slideToggle('medium');
            $('#menu1 > li > a').click(function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('expanded').toggleClass('collapsed').parent().find('> ul').slideToggle('medium');
            });
            $('#example1 .expand_all').click(function() {
                $('#menu1 > li >  a.collapsed').addClass('expanded').removeClass('collapsed').parent().find('>  ul').slideDown('medium');
            });
            $('#example1 .collapse_all').click(function() {
                $('#menu1 > li > a.expanded').addClass('collapsed').removeClass('expanded').parent().find('> ul').slideUp('medium');
            });
        }, 250);
    });
```

HTML

```
<div id="example1">
    <ul id="menu1" class="example_menu">
        <li><a class="collapsed">Mobile</a>
    <ul>
        <li><h2>TEST1</h2><br>

    </ul>
    </li>
        <li class="footer"><span> </span></li>
        <li><a class="collapsed">Landline</a>
    <ul>
        <li><h2>TEST2</h2><br>

    </ul>
    </li>
```

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/EfURx/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All I needed was an accordion menu, sorted!

Answer (score 0):

I have made something for you :) I hope that will helps you.
[AUTO CLOSE COLLAPSIBLE](http://jsfiddle.net/UUhMa/1/)

```
$('.openMe').each(function() {
    var coll = $(this);
    coll.trigger('expand');
});

$('.openMe').each(function() {
    var coll = $(this);
    coll.trigger('collapse'); 
});
```

Good work

Comment: Thanks for this but I like the way my version slowly opens up as opposed to instantly like yours. Either is there any basic code we could add to mine to solve the original question or can we edit the transition type of yours from instant to gradual/sliding if you know what i mean

Comment: I will send you on monday something :)

Answer (score 0):

solved by using the 'Accordion' option on these range of menus file:///Users/johnfarrell/Desktop/collapsible-menu/collapsible-menu.html

Comment: why you are posting this path?